# Angular 1.5+ ng-redux with Observables

Tags: angularjs, redux, rxjs

I have an angular 1.5+ app, integrated with everything ideal minus Angular 2. (I have Webpack, Typescript, I'm using classes, etc).

I have started with ng-redux and I'm wondering how to properly use observables with [ng-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux).  I see libraries like [Redux-Observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) but the single Angular 1 example is *REALLY* concise.

My use case comes especially worthwhile in a case where I would like multiple services to be notified of a `login`/`logout` event, which I believe is an optimal case for observables here.

I have implemented this type of thing without redux, and I could also observe properties the old fashioned way, but I'd much rather do it the way that is closest to an angular-2 paradigm, if there is one.

*Basically:*
**Service 1:**
  -> Observe Service 2 Login event

**Service 2:**
  -> Make http call
  -> Login

**Service 1:**
  -> React to login event
*(using redux dispatching, so obviously there's more things at play. But that is the idea).*

If I should just use the observables as I would in a normal angular app, why do these libraries exist? What is the correct or mostly-correct way of going about this (aside from just moving to angular 2, as that isn't possible at the moment)

Comment: I'd say this question is mainly opinionated - I've been working on a project where there was a central service that basically contained a bunch of BehaviorSubjects which all the other services subscribed to. But your login case sounds like the perfect example-case of an epic to me - and when you plan to use Redux-Observable I think you won't get around the fact, that many parts will not be in services any more but epics, which means that a lot of stuff will be "outside" of angular _or_ if you want to do it "your custom way" with services you won't find the perfect solution, but your own.

Comment: @olsn thank you, I'm diving deeper into `redux-observable`.  Having things "outside" of Angular, in this case, is actually a good thing, no?  If a service observes a value and the value updates, and the service updates the controller accordingly, angular will display that change in the view template.  We then gained performance (and maybe clarity) from that observable, and didn't lose anything.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sure it can be good, but still highly opinionated - my personal opinion is: If you HAVE to use angular1, use the stuff where you find a lot of help in case you need some because the days of angular1 are kind of counted(like flash at its time) - if angular1 is not mandatory for your project: use something else: a2, react, vue, inferno, cycle ... all better than a1 (just my personal opinion, i've been developing angular for the past ~4.5 years now and loved it until many better things came along :) )

Comment: Just a small follow-up (I asked this question 1.5 years ago) - I have since switched to Angular 2 and Love It. :)